# For-loop not indexing correctly

Tags: procedural-programming, infinite-loop

I have a question. Why does my result start with J = 2? I write another loop but it start 1 i confused-i need help

```
 k = 36;
x = 0.15;
in = {{0, 42}, {12, 45}, {24, 88}, {36, 272}, {48, 342}, {60, 
    288}, {72, 240}, {84, 198}, {96, 162}, {108, 133}, {120, 
    110}, {132, 90}, {144, 79}, {156, 68}, {168, 61}, {180, 56}, {192,
     54}, {204, 51}, {216, 48}, {228, 45}, {240, 42}};
n = Length[in];
Qin = Interpolation[in];
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  If[in[[i, 2]] >= in[[i + 1, 2]], deltT = in[[i, 1]]/5]; 
  If[deltT != 0, Break[]]];
c1 = (deltT/k - 2*x)/(2*(1 - x) + deltT/k);
c2 = (deltT/k + 2*x)/(2*(1 - x) + deltT/k);
c3 = (2*(1 - x) - deltT/k)/(2*(1 - x) + deltT/k);
c = c1 + c2 + c3;
input = {};
deltTplus1 = 0;
deltTplus2 = 0;
For[i = 1, deltTplus2 < in[[n, 1]], i++,
  deltTplus2 = deltT + deltTplus2;
  If[i == 1, AppendTo[input, in[[i, 1]]]]; 
  AppendTo[input, deltTplus2]];
For[i = 1, deltTplus1 < in[[n, 1]], i++,
  deltTplus1 = deltT + deltTplus1;
   If[i == 1, AppendTo[input, in[[i, 2]]]]; 
  AppendTo[input, Qin[deltTplus1]]];
input = Transpose[Partition[input, i]];
n = Length[input];
y = {"j", "Qout", "Q"};
Qout = 0;
Q = input[[1, 2]];
Reap[For[j = 1, j <= n, j++; Sow[j];
      If[j + 1 == n, 
       Q = (input[[j + 1, 2]])*c1*0.25 + (input[[j + 1, 2]])*c2 + 
         Qout*c3; Qout = Q; Sow[Qout]; Break[]];
      Qout = Q;
      Q = (input[[j + 1, 2]])*c1 + (input[[j, 2]])*c2 + Qout*c3;
      Sow[Qout];
       Sow[Q]];][[2, 1]]~Partition~3;
g = %;
Join[{y}, g] // Matrix Form
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

Your last for loop has

```
Reap[For[j = 1, j <= n, j++; Sow[j];
```

whereas I *think* you actually mean

```
Reap[For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, Sow[j];
```

(note the comma `,` rather than semicolon `;` after `j++`).

But, without understanding your code or intent, it's hard to help any further.

Comment: Just another issue that wouldn't have come up if OP had used `Do` instead of `For`...

Comment: Or perhaps `Reap[For[j = 1, j <= n, Sow[j++], ...]